# Must I list my committee members as co-authors on a manuscript after being dismissed from grad school?

Tags: publications, authorship

I was a graduate student at a university in the US about two years ago and I was working on a thesis. I was an international student and my advisory committee thought that my writing skills were extremely poor and I was asked to quit the program (though I didn't agree with their decision). I had done some literature review during the program and I recently decided to submit that as a review paper in a fairly decent journal. I just got the decision from the editor saying that the paper could be accepted with minor revision.

Now, I would like your opinion on whether I should contact my advisory committee to see if they would be willing to be the co-authors on the paper. Since I worked on this manuscript while I was a graduate student at that university and did get some help with the corrections on my writing (especially grammar -- I did not use any data from any of my supervisors), do you think I must include them as co-authors on the paper? Do I need to include my previous university as my affiliation? Should I contact them and offer them co-authorship? What do I do if they decline or do not respond?

Since I spent a good amount of time and worked really hard on this manuscript, I would like to get it published. I would really appreciate your opinion on what I should be doing at this point to avoid any infraction of others' intellectual property.

Comment: Did the committee members do anything to help with the production of the paper?

Comment: Your English writing skills seem OK to me...

Answer (score 8):

**Unless they made scientific contributions, do not list them as co-authors.** Proofreading and grammar help is cause for an acknowledgment, not co-authorship. If they contributed scientifically, then you have an ethical obligation to list them. If it is a borderline case, I would err on the side of not including them, given that they basically fired you.

**You do need to list that institution as your affiliation.** Even though you are no longer there, they funded you while you did this research (presumably) and deserve to have the attribution. Further, your contract may require this.

Edit: there was a (now-deleted) follow-up question about whether it's necessary to seek permission to acknowledge someone. My gut feeling is no, but check out: [Is it necessary to ask permission before including someone in the acknowledgements of a research paper?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/19604/is-it-necessary-to-ask-permission-before-including-someone-in-the-acknowledgemen)

Comment: Permission to acknowledge is required in some journals.